# Reading from a text file and storing the data into a table has produced a corrupted table using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I need to read data from a text file and store it int a table. I need to also use the data to calculate a wage for each employee( the test file lists the employee: id: rate: hours worked) the calculate wage needs to be displayed and the table itself needs to list the employees in order from highest to lowest wage, as well as display the total sum of the wages. Below is the text file:(note there is no whitespace between the two lines, it is added for clarity in this post)

```
Mike:Jones:567:25.75:67

Sue:Smith:45:30.25:82

Ann:Barber:2:15.45:39

Billy:Simpson:1234:10.15:65

Barabara:Stone:75:45.33:22

Alan:Colllins:17:12.75:73

Cindy:Davis:210:13.67:45

Eilein:Ferguson:62:53.36:17

Gordon:Howard:981:9.89:31

Bob:Jones:295:14.73:43
```

When I attempt to do this the table comes out rather corrupted. the output is below:

First Name | Last Name | Employee ID | Hourly Rate($) | Hours | Wage($)

```
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
       |           |-9.25596e+61 |   -9.25596e+61 |-9.25596e+61 | -9.25596e+61
```

The total weekly wage is:

Below is the code I am using to try and complete this.

```
 include <cmath>
 include <string>
 include <stream>
 include <iostream>
 include <stream>
 include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 void swap(double* xp, double* yp)
{
double temp = *xp;
*xp = *yp;
*yp = temp;
 }

 void selectionSort(double arr[], int n)
 {
 int i, j, min_idx; 
 for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
 { 
    min_idx = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
            min_idx = j;

    swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[I]);
  }
}

 int main()
{

 ifstream myFile("Assignment4.txt");
 if (!myFile.is_open())
 {
    cout << "File Failed to Open!" << endl;
    return 0;
 }
 const int n = 100;
 string firstname[n], lastname[n];
 double id[n], hours[n], rate[n], wage[n], totalwage;
 unsigned int i = 0;
 string myString;
 string line;
 cout << "First Name |" << " Last Name |" << " Employee ID |" << " Hourly Rate($) |" << " Hours |" << 
 " Wage($)" << endl;
 while (getline(myFile, line))
 {

    stringstream ss(line);
    getline(ss, firstname[i], ':');
    getline(ss, lastname[i], ':');
    getline(ss, myString, ':');
    id[i] = stoi(myString);
    getline(ss, myString, ':');
    rate[i] = stoi(myString);
    getline(ss, myString, '\n');
    hours[i] = stoi(myString);

    if (hours[i] <= 40)
        wage[i] = rate[i] * hours[i];
    else
        wage[i] = rate[i] * 40 + ((hours[i] - 40) * rate[i] * 1.5);

    totalwage += wage[i];
    i = i + 1;
    selectionSort(wage, i);


    cout << setw(10) << firstname[i] << " |" << setw(10)
        << lastname[i] << " |" << setw(12)
        << id[i] << " |" << setw(15)
        << rate[i] << " |" << setw(6)
        << hours[i] << " | " << wage[i] << endl;
 }
 cout << "The total weekly wage is: ";
 myFile.close();
}
```

if anyone knows why it is outputting the data this way and how it can be fixed please help. Im using c++ with visual studio 2019.

Comment: In `selectionSort` what is `I`? Why are you implementing sort anyway? Just use `std::sort`.

Comment: What is the format of your input data? Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If your input data has spaces after the `:`, then you need to account for that when reading the data.

Comment: I included the text file

Comment: Rather than using parallel arrays, I recommend using a single array of a structure (or class).  Parallel arrays can get out of sync, and a pain to sort.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb:  if you are using parallel arrays, you may want to convert to a vector of structure.

```
struct Record
{
    std::string    first_name;
    std::string    last_name;
    double         id; // ??? Is the ID really floating point?
    double         rate;
    double         hours;
    double         wage;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};
```

Overloading of the extraction operator is not required, but simplifies the code.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    char separator;
    std::getline(input, r.first_name, ':');
    std::getline(input, r.last_name, ':');
    input >> r.id; input >> separator;
    input >> r.rate; input >> separator;
    input >> r.hours;  input >> separator;
    input >> r.wage;
    input.ignore(100000, '\n'); // Ignore any remaining characters until end of line.
    return input;
}
```

Your input code could look like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (myFile >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

Sorting the array would require overloading the `operator<`:

```
struct Record
{
    //...
    bool operator<(const Record& r)
    {
        if (last_name == r.last_name)
        {
             return first_name < r.first_name;
        }
        return last_name < r.last_name;
    }
};
```

The sorting operation would be simplified to:

```
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end());
```

Another rule of thumb:  if you think your program is too long or too big, it usually is and can be simplified.